# How to add new user in admin page in django?

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I am trying to add user in admin page in django. Whenever I register in my site form it adds itself but whenever I try to add it in admin page, it gave me the error message.

```
NotImplementedError at /admin/auth/user/add/
UNKNOWN command not implemented for SQL SAVEPOINT "s6856_x1"

C:\Users\Bilal\Envs\trial\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py in parse
handler = self.FUNC_MAP[sm_type]
```

Comment: Which version of django are you using?

Comment: I am using django 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

There currently is [a bug](https://github.com/nesdis/djongo/issues/258) with Django version 2.2 and Djongo.

#### Solution

**Downgrade your Django version** to a <2.2 version until this bug is fixed in the library.

Comment: Did you downgrade Django in your virtual environment?

Comment: I downgraded it but it is giving me error which I have updated in above code.

Comment: That new error means that a dependency is missing. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937343/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror/37937503) explains the error and how to fix it.

Comment: Keep the downgraded Django version until the Djongo library is fixed tho.

Comment: Use Django 2.1.8