# No app named 'account' in my project but django still throws django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, anaconda

Traceback :

```
File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\makemigrations.py", line 87, in handle
    loader = MigrationLoader(None, ignore_no_migrations=True)
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration auth.0012_user_following dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('account', '0002_contact')
```

pip freeze txt file link:

https://github.com/shyamparmar29/pip-freeze/blob/master/freeze.docx

There's no app named account in my project but i am still getting this error. I have tried to delete all pycache and migration files but it is not helping.

I even tried to run the project in a virtual environment but i am still getting this error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

do these steps:

1- delete migrations folder in each app

2- delete database tables or simply delete it completely

3- run ./manage.py makemigrations appname for each app

4- run ./manage.py migrate

5- finally run the server and see what happens

if it does not work again see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937343/django-db-migrations-exceptions-nodenotfounderror).

edit:
delete your DB and run

> python manage.py migrate --fake auth zero

then make migrations again.

Comment: I have tried all the steps. It still throws me the same error

Comment: please add the output of ./manage showmigrations and your pip freeze out put to your question

Comment: sowmigrations throws me the same error. I have pasted the freeze output link.

Comment: ok, I think I know what is happening here, you have installed many third parties and your auth model has an extra migration, I think this extra migration is created by a third parties module that you have passed your account app, have you tried any thing like that? some Django third parties create their own migration files if they have custom Models it must be one of that migration files

Answer (score 0):

**You can try the following specific operations as follows:**

1. Delete through the query path under the local python3.8 file:

   https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMe2r.png ( reference )
2. Delete the migration file that is determined to be wrong, here is the last file starting with 0012.
3. Re-execute python3 manage.py makemigrations after deleting
4. Execute python3 manage.py migrate

At this point, the migration operation should be normal.

**Note: You can also search and delete through the library under the pycharm project, the path is the same as above. It is easy to find and operate.**