# Django Migration "NodeNotFoundError"

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

When I run `python manage.py runserver` this error occurs:

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 1045, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2288.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\threading.py", line 982, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 120, in inner_run
    self.check_migrations()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 458, in check_migrations
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS])
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 18, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 274, in build_graph
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\loader.py", line 248, in build_graph
    self.graph.validate_consistency()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in validate_consistency
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 195, in <listcomp>
    [n.raise_error() for n in self.node_map.values() if isinstance(n, DummyNode)]
     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\django\db\migrations\graph.py", line 58, in raise_error
    raise NodeNotFoundError(self.error_message, self.key, origin=self.origin)
django.db.migrations.exceptions.NodeNotFoundError: Migration account.0001_initial dependencies reference nonexistent parent node ('auth', '0011_alter_user_first_name_max_length.py')
```

This code was running without trouble earlier, suddenly the problem arises.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: *something* must have changed, if it was running fine earlier.

Comment: Like [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37937343)?

Comment: Did you just add custom user model? If previous migrations depend on user, adding custom user model later can mess them up. Quick and dirty solution in this case would be deleting all files except `__init__.py` in migrations folder, then running `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`. Make sure to save previous state of migrations folder in case you mess it up though.